# Replace Video URLs with Youtube Embed Code in Joomla

Tags: javascript, joomla, youtube, joomla-extensions

I'm building a module for Joomla using [mod_custom_js](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-modules/17122) which is meant to find a Youtube URL in an article and replace it with an embedded video. This is the code I have so far:

```
loadvid();
function loadvid(){
    var page = document.getElementById('main');
    var vid_location = page.innerHTML.search("http://www.youtube.com");
    var sub_end = page.innerHTML.substring(vid_location, page.length).search("</p>");
    var url_end = vid_location + sub_end;
    var video_url = page.innerHTML.substring(vid_location, url_end);
    var video_id = video_url.split('v=')[1];
    var embed_code = '<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'+ video_id +'?hd=1&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;showinfo=0" width="160" height="100" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>';
    page.innerHTML = page.innerHTML.replace(video_url, embed_code);
}
```

So far, it's not doing anything. Have I made a mistake or have I failed to configure something properly?

EDIT: I've altered the code so that it works in isolation on a static page, but it's still not working in Joomla.

EDIT 2: It's a Joomla problem. I can't access the article content. It doesn't appear in the document. I'm looking for tools to access/alter article content in Joomla.

Comment: You have used double quotes twice on the same line. Change the quotes wrapped around `<iframe>` to single quotes. If this doesn't do anything, then try using `console.log()` for each variable to see if they are working.

Comment: Thanks for the quote error. I didn't get anything in the console, so I'll see if I missed any more bugs, but it seems to not be running at all.